# Picture's validation in height, width and format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Requirement specfication:

- Upload a picture from a webform (ASP.NET MVC application) to my database.
- validation of the picture's width and height should be performed before
  applying into "app data" category.
- Validate the picture's format. The following format should be gif,
  jpeg,jpg and png

Problem:
Have tried googling 'round in the Internet but can't find a solution to my requirement specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil Haack's blog post should solve your problem: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

The HttpPostedFileBase type allows you to check for the picture's mimetype or you can find [the extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx). To find the width and height of the picture you can use [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx).